# Azure App Service - run crontab/scheduled task besides flask server

Tags: azure, cron, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service which runs a flask server. The startup command of the container is

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 app:app
```

where **app.py** contains the flask server.

Is it possible to run a recurring task (python script) on the same machine? Any solution (crontab, launching a second python process) would be fine. I googled this but didn't find a way to do it in practice.

Any hints?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Azure Functions (which supports Python) with time trigger (cron format) and deploy it into the same app service you already have.